# When trying to print information from xml file in php, formatting marks are printed rather than used

Tags: php, xml

I'm using the php code:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("getCurrentTrains.xml");

settype($message, "string");
$trains = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName("objTrainPositions");

foreach($trains as $train ) {
    $messages = $train->getElementsByTagName("PublicMessage");
    $message = $messages->item(0)->nodeValue;
    print("$message <br />");
}
```

To read in the xml file, and then print out the messages. But when I run it to look at the messages, the messages print with the formatting marks embeded in them. 
Like:

> "A127\nBelfast Central to Dublin Connolly\nExpected Departure 12:35 ".

I don't understand how to make the "\n"s become new lines rather than appear in the output.

Comment: use nl2br() php function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you try to use the "Irish Rail Realtime API"? The information page for it says:

> Public Message is the latest information on the train uses \n for a
>   line break eg
>   `AA509\n11:00 - Waterford to Dublin Heuston (0 minslate)\nDeparted Waterford next stop Thomastown`

So it the xml text node contains \n for linebreaks. You will have to replace them:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load("getCurrentTrains.xml");
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
// the xml uses a namespace, register a prefix for it
$xpath->registerNamespace('rail', 'http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/');

// iterate all `PublicMessage` elements
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//rail:PublicMessage') as $message) {
  // replace "\n" with a xhtml line break
  echo str_replace('\n', '<br />', $message->nodeValue), "<br/>\n";
}
```

Example at: https://eval.in/119688

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
print(nl2br($message ));
```

Comment: This will not work, the \n is part of the string value. It is not an escaped linefeed in a PHP string literal.

Comment: If you write a double quoted string literal in php source, the \n gets decoded to the actual linefeed character. nl2br converts that linefeed character, not a string consisting of a backslash and the letter n: https://eval.in/119920

Comment: ok i get it thanks men i got new ,but @shannon Birch string in "".

Comment: The string is read from an external datasource, not from the php source. In XML a &#10; would get decoded to the linefeed (by the xml parser).

Comment: ok thanks .but when i work with xml read then i use nl2br() then it work proper but i don't no the problem.like this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49713/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-thw)